# Why QObject needs to be the first in case of multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qobject, moc

According to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/moc.html#multiple-inheritance-requires-qobject-to-be-first the `QObject` must be the first in the base classes when using multiple inheritance.

Is this because of some limitation in the `moc` tool or C++ memory layout problems are taken into consideration too, thus this restriction came into existence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that we have a class `Test` declared as:

```
class Test : public Foo, public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    [..]
};
```

If you take a look at the `moc_test.cpp` file that the `moc` tool has generated, you will see something like:

```
[..]
const QMetaObject Command::staticMetaObject = {
    { &Foo::staticMetaObject, qt_meta_stringdata_Command,
      qt_meta_data_Command, &staticMetaObjectExtraData }
};
[..]
```

Compiler will complain about `staticMetaObject` not being the member of `Foo`, as `Foo` is not a `QObject`. For some reason the `moc` tool generates this code taking the **first** parent class. Thus if you declare `Test` as:

```
class Test : public QObject, public Foo {};
```

The generated code will look fine to compiler.

I think this is made just for convenience because `moc` tool will hardly know which of the parent classes is a `QObject` without parsing the whole hierarchy.

**Note:** If you don't use the `Q_OBJECT` macro, you can derive your class from others in any order.

Comment: I think it is not only the convenience, as within the derived class object the pointer to base classes will be at different positions (will have different offset). And I think that qt does some stupid casts.